# SQLite data insert not reflected in table

Tags: sqlite, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I can insert my data, but I can't show them in my table view. I tried `[tableview reloadData]`
but with no success

Here is my code:

```
-(void)gButtonTapped:(id)sender
{  


    NSLog(@"right nav bar button is  hit%@ ",storePaths);
    //[self readAnimalsFromDatabase2];

    appDelegate = (DatabaseTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    sqlite3 *database;

     sqlite3_stmt *compiled_statement1;
     if(sqlite3_open([storePaths UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
         //const char *sqlStatement = 


         NSString *newQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into cat_tbl (cat_id,names,imgs) values ('12','test1','r.png')"];

        // NSString *newQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from list_tbl"];

        const char *sql = [newQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


        NSLog(@"update query is %@",newQuery);

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiled_statement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int result = sqlite3_step(compiled_statement1);
            sqlite3_reset(compiled_statement1);
            NSLog(@"result %d", result);

            if(result != SQLITE_ERROR) {
                int lastInsertId =  sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
                NSLog(@"x %d", lastInsertId);
        }




        }

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiled_statement1);


    sqlite3_close(database);
    [tableView reloadData];// this is also  not working 

}
```

Comment: kindly suggest as how to reflect new data  on table view :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your table view data source by calling select query or update your data source by adding new values as they got inserted successfully in the data base.